# how progressive calculation in php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Good morning, I have a problem for the progressive points tally on sales.
so when a sales person can sell cars in one month. as many as six cars then on the sale to four then pointnya will increase. like in the picture below

How do I make a program in php?

[image]

Comment: What have you done till yet? How did you derive the formula in excel?

Comment: I  am confused as a progressive step, make the confused logic in php

Comment: Does points increase after every 4th sale? Also increases by what ratio?

Comment: on sale 1-4 earn points normal. and when the sale to 5-6 will earn normal point + the step points. and when the sale to 7-8 will earn normal points + step points + step points. detail can be seen in the picture

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala can u help me?

Comment: Make some initial logic in php will help you correcting it.